# Calculating relative strength index over a period

Tags: python, beginner, finance

I'm looking for a review on my code. I am also looking for ways to transform this function into something more Pythonic. I'm fairly new to Python, so any advice would be appreciated.

```
def get_rsi(self, period):
    rsi = []

    for i in xrange(1, len(self.hist_d) - period + 1):
        gains = 0.0
        losses = 0.0

        for j in xrange(i, i + period):
            diff = self.hist_d[j][2] - self.hist_d[j - 1][2]

            if diff > 0:
                gains += diff
            elif diff < 0: 
                losses += abs(diff)

        rsi.append(round(100 - (100 / (1 + gains / losses)), 2))

    return rsi
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your code is already pretty Pythonic.

There is a bug in your code. If no losses were reported in that window then `losses == 0.0` which when you append to `rsi` will throw a `ZeroDivisionError`.

There are two suggestions I would make:

1. Use `zip` (or `izip` if possible)

   The `zip` function takes two iterables and combines them. It essentially returns:

   ```
   >>>zip([1,2,3], ['a','b','c'])
   [(1, 'a'), (2, 'b'), (3, 'c')]
   ```

   We can use this instead of directly indexing through `j` and `j-1`.
2. `If-Else`

   Currently your if-statement looks like this:

   ```
   if diff > 0:
       gains += diff
   elif diff < 0: 
       losses += abs(diff)
   ```

   I would recommend making the `elif` into a simple `else`. This is because anything that the `elif` won't catch is if `diff == 0` and since `losses == losses + 0`, it won't effect `losses`. Also, you remove a comparision using a simple `else`.

With these suggestions taken into account (plus the simple bug fix), we can refactor your code a little bit:

```
def get_rsi(self, period):
    rsi=[]
    for i in range(len(self.hist_d)-period):
        gains = 0.0
        losses = 0.0

        window = self.hist_d[i:i+period+1]
        for year_one, year_two in zip(window, window[1:]):
            diff = year_two - year_one

            if diff > 0:
                gains += diff
            else:
                losses += abs(diff)

        # Check if `losses` is zero. If so, `100/(1 + RS)` will practically be 0.
        if not losses:
            rsi.append(100.00)
        else:
            rsi.append(round(100 - (100 / (1 + gains / losses)), 2))

    return rsi
```

Answer (score 5):

It looks like you want a moving window of length `period` over `self.hist_d` (and then a moving window of length `2` over each of those windows, to get pairs of consecutive years). An efficient way of doing that is provided in the old version of [the `itertools` documentation](https://docs.python.org/release/2.3.5/lib/itertools-example.html):

```
from itertools import islice, izip

def window(seq, n=2):
    "Returns a sliding window (of width n) over data from the iterable"
    "   s -> (s0,s1,...s[n-1]), (s1,s2,...,sn), ...                   "
    it = iter(seq)
    result = tuple(islice(it, n))
    if len(result) == n:
        yield result    
    for elem in it:
        result = result[1:] + (elem,)
        yield result
```

I heard of this via [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6822725/rolling-or-sliding-window-iterator-in-python), where there are also other options for the same task.

You can then use this to process your results:

```
def get_rsi(self, period):
    for series in window(self.hist_d, period):
        gains = losses = 0.0
        for year1, year2 in window(series): # or 'izip(series, series[1:])'
            diff = year2[2] - year1[2]
            ...
```

Comment: He doesn't want a static second window of size two. [Its of size `period`](http://codepad.org/d6vyIdVH).

Comment: @DarinDouglass the inner, length-2 window in my code is for `diff = self.hist_d[j][2] - self.hist_d[j - 1][2]` - it iterates over the whole `series`. I have edited slightly to hopefully clarify this.

Comment: Oh ok, I get what you meant now. It probably would be more clear as 'the difference of each pair of successive years' or something like that :P

Comment: @DarinDouglass edited - is that clearer?

Comment: Yeah that looks fine :D